# expl3: wrapping `\tl_map_function` around `int_step_function`

Tags: expl3

The code below shows what I'm trying to get at and the stumbling blocks:

```
\documentclass{l3doc}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_set:Npn \__foo:n #1
{ 
    (#1)
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_map_function:nN
    {{a}{b}}
\__foo:n % (a)(b) %OK

\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl
{
    \int_step_inline:nnnn{1}{1}{2}
    {
        %{ % inner braces
            \int_to_alph:n{#1}
        %}
    }
}

\\\tl_map_function:nN
    \l_tmpa_tl
\__foo:n % wanted (a)(b), getting (ab), including with inner braces

% \tl_map_function:nN
%{
%   \int_step_inline:nnnn{1}{1}{2}
%   {
%       \int_to_alph:n{#1}
%   } % wanted: (a)(b)
%% Getting:
%%! Missing number, treated as zero.
%%<to be read again> 
%%                   )
%% l.N } \__foo:n       
%%} \__foo:n

%% Same error for:
%\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl
%{
%   \int_step_inline:nnnn{1}{1}{2}
%   {
%       %{
%           \int_to_alph:n{#1}
%       %}
%   }
%}


\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look with `\tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl` at the value, you'll see it is *not* `ab`, but very different from it.

You have to use `\tl_set:Nx` and `\int_step_function:nnnN` in order to get `ab` as the contents of `\l_tmpa_tl`. Next you need `\tl_map_function:NN` in order to use the value of `\l_tmpa_tl` and not the token itself as it would be with `\tl_map_function:nN`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npn \__foo:n #1
 { 
    (#1)
 }

First:~\tl_map_function:nN {{a}{b}} \__foo:n

\par

\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl
 {
    \int_step_function:nnnN{1}{1}{2} \int_to_alph:n
 }

Second:~\tl_map_function:NN \l_tmpa_tl \__foo:n 

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I did use `tl_set:Nx` but with a brace around `int_to_alpha` (which I can't justify in hindsight, wearing blinders)